# Aptitude is freezing when trying to install a package

Tags: apt, 18.04, aptitude

I'm following the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html). I'm trying to learn how to use Aptitude. I recently upgraded my ubuntu desktop from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS.

So I entered aptitude with `sudo aptitude`, and I marked a package for installation, and pressed `g` to install. Then this text appeared in the center of the screen: "Trying to fix broken packages..."

Now it's just stuck there, I can't do anything, is there any way to fix this? It's happening for any package I try to install or uninstall.

[image: apt]

**EDIT**

Output for `sudo apt update`

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Output for `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Consider, after closing `aptitude`, opening a terminal and entering the commands `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Copy the output, and [edit] your question to include it. The information needed to better diagnose the problem with the package system should be in that output.

Comment: That said, over a thousand broken packages sounds problematic.

Comment: I've added the output, what should I do now?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 you should ask yourself the question - why this dependency breakage happen? Did you tried to cancel pending actions with `<F10>`, *Actions*, *Cancel pending actions*, `<Enter>`? Will it change anything?

Comment: That output seems inconsistent with the aptitude output, it does not show any problem. What package are you trying to install?

Comment: I tried installing some package in games, but it doesn't really matter which package I try, it's doing the same thing, freezing.